# How do you use xlsread with MATLAB and OS X?

Tags: macos, excel, matlab, file-io

When trying to call xlsread, I get the warning:

> Warning: Could not start Excel
>   server for import, 'basic' mode
>   will be used. Refer to HELP
>   XLSREAD for more information.

The helpfile suggests to me because I am running OSX, I do not have an excel COM server running which results in this warning. I'd like to either find a solution or confirm that it is irresolvable.

Specifications: I'm running MATLAB R2011a and OS X Lion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main options:

1. Upgrade to R2012b, which [allows reading sheets and ranges in Excel files on all platforms](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html)
2. Use any of the (somewhat involved) approaches discussed [in this post of Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/xlswrite-for-mac-linux/)