# Warning: Could not start Excel server for import, 'basic' mode will be used. Refer to HELP XLSREAD for more information.

Tags: matlab

The data looks like this:

```
'name'  'date'      value1  value2
'A'          'E'        350 25
'B'          'F'        204 22
'C'          'G'        1022    117
'D'          'H'        369 53
```

I want to store the last two columns into a matrix. I tried

```
column=xlsread('fileName.xlsx', 'D:D')
```

and

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('fileName.xlsx')
```

and I got errors like the following: 
Warning: Could not start Excel server for import, 'basic' mode will be used. Refer to HELP XLSREAD for more information.

I found the following related post. 
[How do you use xlsread with MATLAB and OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768598/how-do-you-use-xlsread-with-matlab-and-os-x). But the matlab I am using is R2014b. It should be able to work, isnot it? Many thanks.

Comment: are you on OS X? do you have excel installed?

Comment: No. Windows it is.  I have excel.